# How to delete lines of output, python?

Tags: python-3.x

So here is my code:

```
Krotos = [100, 25]

Sephiroth = [100, 25]

endGame = 0

def checkHealth():
  global endGame
  if Krotos[0] == 0:
    print("Game Over")
    endGame = 1
  if Sephiroth[0] == 0:
    print("You Win")
    endGame = 1

def krotosAttack():
  Sephiroth[0] -= Krotos[1]

def printHealth():
  print("Krotos:", Krotos[0])
  print("Sephiroth:", Sephiroth[0])

def sephirothAttack():
  Krotos[0] -= Sephiroth[1]

def checkInput():
  print("Click 1 for attack\nClick 2 for shield")
  x = int(input(":"))
  if x == 1:
    krotosAttack()

while endGame == 0:
  checkInput()
  checkHealth()
  if endGame == 0:
    sephirothAttack()
    checkHealth()
  printHealth()
```

My output is:

```
Click 1 for attack
Click 2 for shield
:1
Krotos: 75
Sephiroth: 75
Click 1 for attack
Click 2 for shield
:
```

How can I get rid of the first three lines so it only shows the newest information? Any new ideas would be useful. I have tried using google but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below :

```
Krotos = [100, 25]

Sephiroth = [100, 25]

endGame = 0



def clear():
    import os

    os.system("clear") # Linux
    os.system("cls")   # Windows

def checkHealth():
  global endGame
  if Krotos[0] == 0:
    print("Game Over")
    endGame = 1
  if Sephiroth[0] == 0:
    print("You Win")
    endGame = 1

def krotosAttack():
  Sephiroth[0] -= Krotos[1]

def printHealth():
  print("Krotos:", Krotos[0])
  print("Sephiroth:", Sephiroth[0])

def sephirothAttack():
  Krotos[0] -= Sephiroth[1]

def checkInput():
  print("Click 1 for attack\nClick 2 for shield")
  x = int(input(":"))
  if x == 1:
    krotosAttack()
    clear()                    # -------------> Call clear function after your input

while endGame == 0:
  checkInput()
  checkHealth()
  if endGame == 0:
    sephirothAttack()
    checkHealth()
  printHealth()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the console after every attack:

```
import os
os.system("cls") #windows
os.system("clear") #linux
```